# Design an interface with appropriate declarations of Base class pointers - cpp

Tags: c++, design-patterns, interface

I have a little design problem.

Assume I have this interface:

```
class IBase {
public:
    virtual void Run() = 0;
    virtual void DoSomethingWithData(IData* data) = 0;
    virtual ~IBase() = 0;
};
```

I want to implement derived classes, so I need to build a derived class for IData (let's call it DData). IData is basically an empty interface:

```
class IData {
public:
    IData();
    virtual ~IData() = 0;
};
```

The problem is that in DoSomethingWithData method that I implement - I need to refer to specific members in DData, but I can't because the pointer is of IData . For example, see implementation of DoSomethingWithData in some derived class:

```
class DData : public IData {
private:
    int m_i;
};

<Derived.h : IBase>
Derived::DoSomethingWithData(IData* data) {
    some_function_call(data->m_i) // cannot be used by the base ptr
}
```

What is the best way to overcome this problem?

dynamic cast on SetData?
Changing the interface (in this way?)?
Other option?

**Edit:**

To clarify the problem:
I have this relation -

```
class A -> uses DataA
class B -> uses DataB
class C -> uses DataC
```

there is a common interface for the classes: Run, DoSomethingWithData.
DoSomethingWithData expects for data, but it does not know what is the data, it depends in the class that we implement.
I need to find the best way to write the interface, without using bad OOP techniques like dynamic_cast.

Comment: Your problem is not clear. Please provide some explanation of what should be possible with the design, maybe what should be prevented with the design. Can you provide code which demonstrates how the design should be used?

Comment: If the classes are to be treated all different, then `IData` really *isn't* their interface. And an empty interface is suspicious by itself - what do the classes have in common? Nothing?

Comment: IBase says it accepts a poimter to IData. *Every* child *must* accept *any* pointer to IData. You cannot cherry pick "the D1Derived will accept a pointer to D1Data and D2Derived will accept a pointer to D2Data". It"s the very first thing they should teach in the OO programming classes, but somehow nobody does, so I have to cover for them all and frankly I'm sick and tired of it.

Comment: @n.m. so you suggest to remove DoSomethingWithData function from the interface, and implement it with the suitable DData in every derived class?

Comment: It could be a reasonable design choice, or it could not work at all, depending on what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Whose base class is `IBase` ?

Comment: It is written: <Derived.h : IBase>

Comment: @n.m The problem is I **want** DoSomethingWithData to be in the base class, since this is the interface which I expect every derived class will implement

Comment: Sigh. Back at square one. If you expect every derived class to accept **any** kind of IData, go ahead and declare your method in your base class. Otherwise your derived classes are **not** implementing the same interface, and you have nothing to put in the base class.

Comment: But I want to force every derived class to implement DoSomethingWithData method! and this method must get the data argument..

Comment: Sorry but it is still unclear to me. I don't know what `<Derived.h : IBase>` is supposed to mean in that context. Is `IBase` a base class of `IData`, `DData`, both or none? According to your code `IData` has no base class and the only base class of `DData` is `IData`.

Comment: No woreies, I am very very patient, I can explain the same thing over and over again. There is no such thing as DoSomethingWithData method. Any method has a signature. You want every derived class to implement DoSomethingWithData method with what parameters?

Comment: "Sorry but it is still unclear to me.": It is like this: IBase -> Derived. IData -> DData
@n.m. I want every derived class to implement DoSomethingWithData method with data parameters. The data is different within every derived class

Comment: I understand full well what you want. You are not the first person to want this very thing. You cannot. OO doesn't work this way. I think you should re-read my first comment several times.

Comment: An interface is a contract. A contract is not something you can.promise to adhere to and then change the terms. If your contract says "here I accept IData" that's what you do, no ifs or buts. You cannot say "I accept something like IData but not exactly, I can't tell you right now what it is because I don't know myself". This is not a contract, it promises nothing to the other party and is not allowed. If you can't promise something specific, you shouldn't promise anything.

Comment: I see. So what is your suggestion to solve this issue?

Comment: This largely depends on how you are going to use pointers to IBase and call DoSomethingWithData from these pointers.

Comment: See my solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution which we chose is using templates (I don't understand why no one suggested it).

```
template <class T>
class IBase {
public:
    virtual void Run() = 0;
    virtual void DoSomethingWithData(const T& data) = 0;
    virtual ~IBase() = 0;
};
```

I think that this is the best solution in this case, since it does not requires anyone to derive from empty interface, and it does declare for some contruct.

I'd like to hear if someone has any reservation for this solution.

Comment: Here every `IBase` class will be of a different kind depending on what kind of `data` it accepts. It's not wrong, it's just not what you asked for in your original question, and by implication it's exactly what was pointed out in the comments.

Comment: I asked for a proper design.. and here it is.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that in `DoSomethingWithData` method that I implement - I need to refer to specific members in `DData`, but I can't because the pointer is of `IData`.

You are passing a pointer to `IData` which is the base class of `DData`. By means of *virtual function dispatch* you may call a member function that is is actually implemented in `DData` through a pointer to `IData`.

The class `DData` derives from `IData`, so you can declare a *virtual member function* in `IData`:

```
class IData {
public:
    IData();
    virtual int getData() = 0; // <-- new virtual function
    virtual ~IData() = 0;
};
```

and then *implement* this function in `DData`:

```
class DData : public IData {
public:
    int getData() override { // <-- implementation
       return m_i;
    }
private:
     int m_i;
};
```

Since this member function is implemented in `DData`, it can access its private data members (i.e.: `m_i`).

When you call `getData()` of a `DData` instance through a `IData` pointer, you will be using `DData`'s implementation.

Comment: You are right, but the problem is that my data is far complicated than "int m_i", and every data derived class can have different data.
One class can have (string s, int i, double d) and other can have (vector<int> v, float f)

Comment: @BinyaminAppelbaum Would it be feasible to perform a *downcast* by means of `dynamic_cast<>` ?

Comment: I'd like to do it, since it is the simplest way to solve the problem.
But dynamic_cast points generally on bad design.. so I wish to have another solution

Comment: @BinyaminAppelbaum I meant, you could keep information in the derived class regarding to the implementation, access this information (via virtual functions) before choosing the derived class to be dynamic casted to.

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't understand. Do you mean I need to dynamic_cast<DData>(data) the pointer at DoSomethingWithData func?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to refer to specific members in DData, but I can't because the pointer is of IData

Interfaces specify a contract. It does not "know" about internal details/representation (aka, things like member variables, private functions, etc.) If your `IData` has to "know" about private member variables of `DData`, you are doing something wrong. Perhaps using an interface for `Data` is wrong. If `Data` is meant to be a POD (plain ol' data) struct, then just have your base class take a `Data` and expose an API that deals with said struct.